# SSRS - Need Help Understanding Expression

Tags: reporting-services

First off, sorry if this has been asked before, but I could not find it anywhere. Searching for "=1'" did not return any results.

I am working on an Epicor SSRS report out of the box and do not know what part of the following expression means:

```
=1'=Sum(Fields!OrderRelNum.Value, "OrderRel")
```

Can anyone tell me what the first part of the expression (=1') is doing? I need to make changes to the report, but don't want to mess anything up.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The apostrophe causes the rest of the line to be a comment which is therefore ignored.

Comment: Thank you! Never knew it was possible to comment out in an expression.